# PyTorch: create non-fully-connected layer / concatenate output of hidden layers

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch

In PyTorch, I want to create a hidden layer whose neurons are not fully connected to the output layer. I try to concatenate the output of two linear layers but run into the following error:

> RuntimeError: size mismatch, m1: [2 x 2], m2: [4 x 4]

my current code:

```
class NeuralNet2(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(NeuralNet2, self).__init__()

        self.input = nn.Linear(2, 40)
        self.hiddenLeft = nn.Linear(40, 2)
        self.hiddenRight = nn.Linear(40, 2)
        self.out = nn.Linear(4, 4)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.input(x)
        xLeft, xRight = torch.sigmoid(self.hiddenLeft(x)), torch.sigmoid(self.hiddenRight(x))
        x = torch.cat((xLeft, xRight))
        x = self.out(x)

        return x
```

I don't get why there is a size mismatch? Is there an alternative way to implement non-fully-connected layers in pytorch?

Comment: I'm not sure if you posted the relevant parts, but that works flawlessly for me... I'm using the following code to instantiate the network:
`net = NeuralNet2()`, as well as some input `x = torch.Tensor(np.array([1,2]))`, and then simply call `net(x)`. Which version are you using?

Comment: After trying out your suggestion x = torch.Tensor(np.array([1,2])) it worked for me too. Networks without concatenation do also accept input with shape [x, amountInputNeurons] while this network only accepts input with shape [amountInputNeurons]. Got to look deeper into concatenation to get back the old behavior. Thanks:) @dennlinger

Comment: Oh, I see. There might be a way to get this behavior by specifically telling the network which concatenation dimension to use. I believe for your case that would then be `torch.cat((xLeft, xRight), axis=1)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out to be a simple comprehension problem with the concatenation function.
Changing
    `x = torch.cat((xLeft, xRight))`
to
    `x = torch.cat((xLeft, xRight), dim=1)`
did the trick.
Thanks @dennlinger